# Users unable to see page content

Tags: permissions

I've imported an Excel spreadsheet into a list, modified and can see it fine.

I then went to the `Page > Setting > Permissions` for this list, clicked the "Home Visitors" and added the group `Domain\domain users` to allow everyone in this group to see it ( they have `read only` permission).

However when users from this group click on the page, it is empty and does not show the list.

If I add the group `Domain\domain users` to the "Home members" group, my users are able to see it, but they can also edit it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have given a permission on page. You should give permissions to your list.

- Go to **List Settings** > **Permissions for this list** > **Stop Inheriting Permission**
- Remove groups to all other permissions you do not want except "Home Visitor"(Whatever your group).
- You can grant permission on any group which you want on this list

Then, when you import list on page, then it will display as per permissions you have given.